# Move saves from cartridge to sd card

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I wonna buy permament digital copy of the game;

Can I somehow transfer my savedata from the cartridge to the inner 3ds memory and continue playing that town in digital game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps from [Nintendo's helpful topic](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/73/~/how-to-use-the-save-data-transfer-tool):

```
What to Do:
 1.Ensure the SD Card inserted into your system has the downloadable version of the software installed.
 2.Connect to the Nintendo eShop and download the "Save Data Transfer Tool." [How to]
 3.Insert the retail version of the software into system.
 4.From the HOME Menu, select the "Save Data Transfer Tool."
 5.Read the on-screen instructions carefully, and tap the transfer button when ready to transfer save data. ◦Do not turn the power OFF or remove the Game Card during the save data transfer process. This can cause the save data to become corrupt or lost. If the save data is lost during the transfer process, it cannot be recovered.
```

Be aware that it doesn't copy the data:

```
•The Save Data Transfer Tool is used to transfer save data; it does not copy save data. Once transferred, the original save data is deleted.
```